# Perl - open a CLI environment and send commands

Tags: perl, bash, ssh, command-line-interface

i'm new with Perl :)

i'm trying to write a simple script just open a CLI environment ( by executing bash command)
and then send a command to that environment (only that environment familiar with this command)

***for example:***
my linux is running in HP server machine.
if i would like to see the memory configuration so under root user i need
to execute: '**hpasmcli**" and then i well get the following environment :

root@xxx:/>% **hpasmcli**
HP management CLI for Linux (v2.0)
Copyright 2008 Hewlett-Packard Development Group, L.P.

---

NOTE: Some hpasmcli commands may not be supported on all Proliant servers.

### Type 'help' to get a list of all top level commands.

hpasmcli>

and now the need to enter "show dimm":

---

NOTE: Some hpasmcli commands may not be supported on all Proliant servers.

### Type 'help' to get a list of all top level commands.

hpasmcli> **show dimm**

then i will get the memory configuration in the server.

so i'm tying to write a Perl script to make this simple task.
i tried to use "expect" and "open(FH,"|/sbin/hpasmcli") but i was able just to log in 
to the CLI environment and not to send the command "show dimm"

Thank you for your help!

Comment: check out http://www.kudos.be/hppro_hw_monitor

Answer (score 1):

You might need to flush the output buffer after every write:

```
open my $CMD, "| /sbin/hpasmcli"
    or die "Couldn't pipe output to hpasmcli: $!";


my $old_out = select $CMD;
$| = 1;    #perl's autoflush global variable which affects the current output file handle
select $old_out;

print {$CMD} "show dimm";
```

Comment: Thank you. i tried it but i got the same result
as i used open(FH,...") it just log in to the CLI environment but not send the second command.

Comment: Try something simpler first: see if you can pipe some output to the cat command.

Comment: probably, you need to add the end of line marker `\n` to the command: `print {$CMD} "show dimm\n";`